# How to get all the mount point information for android device?

Tags: android

How do I get all the mount point information for an Android device programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly part of the android apis, but the underlying linux will tell you about the ones that are *in use* if you read /proc/mounts

As a clarification, in later Android versions Linux's ability to have unique mounts for each process ancestry is leveraged, so the mounts seen by an application process can (and typically will) be different than those seen by something launched from ADB, or a core system process.

Comment: How to comprehend these values obtained from /proc/mounts --->rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0

tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755 0 0

devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0

proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0

sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0

.

Comment: Read the kernel sources or just figure it out from known entires: it appears to be {device, mountpoint, type, options, etc...} but there's no guarantee that won't change at some point.

Comment: thankyou Chris..would you happen to know the answer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/6824604/530993

Answer (score 11):

You can see the partitions known to the system by examining `/proc/partitions`. From my HTC Desire:

```
major minor  #blocks  name

  31        0        640 mtdblock0
  31        1       4608 mtdblock1
  31        2       3072 mtdblock2
  31        3     256000 mtdblock3
  31        4      40960 mtdblock4
  31        5     151168 mtdblock5
 179        0    3872256 mmcblk0
 179        1    2872070 mmcblk0p1
 179        2    1000185 mmcblk0p2
```

The `mtdblock` devices are the phone's internal flash storage. `mmcblk0` is the phone's SD card.

The best way to see what is mounted where is to examine `/proc/self/mountinfo`. This is better than `/proc/mounts` because the latter misses certain information. Again, on my HTC Desire (I added column headings and ran the output through `column -s` for good measure):

```
ID  PARENT  BLOCK  ROOT              MOUNTPOINT                   OPTIONS                             -  TYPE     SOURCE                 SUPEROPTS
1   1       0:1    /                 /                            ro,relatime                         -  rootfs   rootfs                 ro
11  1       0:11   /                 /dev                         rw,relatime                         -  tmpfs    tmpfs                  rw,mode=755
12  11      0:9    /                 /dev/pts                     rw,relatime                         -  devpts   devpts                 rw,mode=600
13  1       0:3    /                 /proc                        rw,relatime                         -  proc     proc                   rw
14  1       0:12   /                 /sys                         rw,relatime                         -  sysfs    sysfs                  rw
15  1       0:13   /                 /acct                        rw,relatime                         -  cgroup   none                   rw,cpuacct
16  1       0:14   /                 /mnt/asec                    rw,relatime                         -  tmpfs    tmpfs                  rw,mode=755,gid=1000
17  1       0:15   /                 /mnt/obb                     rw,relatime                         -  tmpfs    tmpfs                  rw,mode=755,gid=1000
18  11      0:16   /                 /dev/cpuctl                  rw,relatime                         -  cgroup   none                   rw,cpu
19  1       31:3   /                 /system                      ro,relatime                         -  yaffs2   /dev/block/mtdblock3   ro
20  1       31:5   /                 /data                        rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime            -  yaffs2   /dev/block/mtdblock5   rw
21  1       31:4   /                 /cache                       rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime            -  yaffs2   /dev/block/mtdblock4   rw
22  21      31:5   /local/download   /cache/download              rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime            -  yaffs2   /dev/block/mtdblock5   rw
23  1       179:2  /                 /sd-ext                      rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime  -  ext4     /dev/block/mmcblk0p2   rw,commit=19,barrier=0,data=writeback
24  20      179:2  /app              /data/app                    rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime  -  ext4     /dev/block/mmcblk0p2   rw,commit=19,barrier=0,data=writeback
25  20      179:2  /data             /data/data                   rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime  -  ext4     /dev/block/mmcblk0p2   rw,commit=19,barrier=0,data=writeback
26  14      0:6    /                 /sys/kernel/debug            rw,relatime                         -  debugfs  /sys/kernel/debug      rw
27  1       179:1  /                 /mnt/sdcard                  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime     -  vfat     /dev/block/vold/179:1  rw,dirsync,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0602,dmask=0602,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
28  1       179:1  /.android_secure  /mnt/secure/asec             rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime     -  vfat     /dev/block/vold/179:1  rw,dirsync,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0602,dmask=0602,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
29  27      0:17   /                 /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure  ro,relatime                         -  tmpfs    tmpfs                  ro,size=0k,mode=000
```

Comment: "The mtdblock devices are the phone's internal flash storage. mmcblk0 is the phone's SD card.". Doesn't seem to be a valid assumption. On my tablet (Dell Venue 7) which has both internal memory and SD Card there are only mcc* partitions.

Comment: Yes, this is merely an explanatory observation. It is not valid to assume this will be the case on different devices.

Answer (score 3):

**adb shell df -h**

Example

```
  Filesystem      Size  Used Avail   Use%   Mounted on
  tmpfs           3.6G  1.1M  3.6G     1%   /dev
  tmpfs           3.6G     0  3.6G     0%   /mnt
```

Answer (score 1):

/proc/mtd

or on other phones:

/proc/emmc

This will show all the partitions and their names - which may or may not currently be mounted.

Answer (score 0):

this worked with my samsung j5

> adb shell df -h