# how to get the default HTTP USER AGENT from the android device?

Tags: android

How to get the default HTTP USER AGENT and its default settings from the android device?

thanks
Nohsib

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit: See Prakash's answer, which is better for 2.1+.**

Try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#getUserAgentString

Note that this User Agent will only apply for the embedded WebKit browser that's used by default in Android. Unfortunately, you'll need to create a new WebView object to get the user agent. Fortunately, the user agent doesn't change often, so you should only need to run this code once in your application lifetime (unless don't care about performance). Just do:

```
String userAgent = new WebView(this).getSettings().getUserAgentString();
```

Alternatively, you can use the JavaScript method `navigator.getUserAgent()`.

Comment: Thankyou Oleg, if you could kindly share some code snippet on the same, would help.

Comment: Alright, I edited my response. (And next time, don't forget to do a search first.)

Comment: why is it better?

Answer (score 37):

as Varundroid mentioned in his answer,

```
String userAgent = System.getProperty("http.agent");
```

is better way to do it for Android 2.1 and above.

====================

From android source code.

```
public static String getDefaultUserAgent() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(64);
    result.append("Dalvik/");
    result.append(System.getProperty("java.vm.version")); // such as 1.1.0
    result.append(" (Linux; U; Android ");

    String version = Build.VERSION.RELEASE; // "1.0" or "3.4b5"
    result.append(version.length() > 0 ? version : "1.0");

    // add the model for the release build
    if ("REL".equals(Build.VERSION.CODENAME)) {
        String model = Build.MODEL;
        if (model.length() > 0) {
            result.append("; ");
            result.append(model);
        }
    }
    String id = Build.ID; // "MASTER" or "M4-rc20"
    if (id.length() > 0) {
        result.append(" Build/");
        result.append(id);
    }
    result.append(")");
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is good, but if the scheme changes in future devices then it may not be accurate.

Comment: The scheme is a spec, so you can add any values to it as long as it conforms the spec.

Answer (score 3):

When you use web view to access the user-agent, make sure you run the

`new WebView(this).getSettings().getUserAgentString();`

on the UI thread.

If you want access the user agent on background thread.
use

`System.getProperty("http.agent")`

To check whether a user-agent is valid or not use this
https://deviceatlas.com/device-data/user-agent-tester

Answer (score 3):

**Android get User Agent**

An alternative

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    String userAgent = WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(context);
}
```