# HTTP get request from Amazon s3

Tags: android, api, rest, http, amazon-s3

1. In order to access the instructions you must GET the "anvato-resumes/candidates/2015_04/Gaurav_552f065e7a655" resource from this web service:

https://s3.amazonaws.com

2. You must make it appear as if you're sending the GET request by following a link to the resource from http://www.anvato.com/candidates/Gaurav using a Chrome browser on an Android Phone. Otherwise, the web service will give you an Access Denied error.

I have tried following way:

curl  -A "Lynx/2.8.8dev.3 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1" -e "http://www.anvato.com/candidates/Gaurav"  -X GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/anvato-resumes/candidates/2015_04/Gaurav_552f065e7a655

I am using the terminal to make this call. Unfortunately I am getting access denied error. I have a feeling that I should be using android device to make this call.

Comment: Set http.header 'user-agent' as if android device.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824604/how-to-get-the-default-http-user-agent-from-the-android-device

Answer (score 0):

Below Works!

`curl  -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; One Build/KTU84L.H4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.135 Mobile Safari/537.36" -e "http://www.anvato.com/candidates/Gaurav"  -X GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/anvato-resumes/candidates/2015_04/Gaurav_552f065e7a655`